# I have a table which I want to print, but in print preview I want to rotate the whole page

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to rotate print Review using Css and html, how can I solve this problem because all css styles do not apply on it?

Comment: Please share you're code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a media query that will apply only when printing :

You could do something like this:

```
@media print {
  body {
     transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but, as I said not all the Css styles are working